# How can you make logging module functions use a different logger?

Tags: python, logging

I can create a named child logger, so that all the logs output by that logger are marked with it's name. I can use that logger exclusively in my function/class/whatever.

However, if that code calls out to functions in another module that makes use of logging using just the logging module functions (that proxy to the root logger), how can I ensure that those log messages go through the same logger (or are at least logged in the same way)?

For example:

main.py

```
import logging

import other

def do_stuff(logger):
    logger.info("doing stuff")
    other.do_more_stuff()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger("stuff")
    do_stuff(logger)
```

other.py

```
import logging

def do_more_stuff():
    logging.info("doing other stuff")
```

Outputs:

```
$ python main.py 
INFO:stuff:doing stuff
INFO:root:doing other stuff
```

I want to be able to cause both log lines to be marked with the name 'stuff', and I want to be able to do this only changing main.py.

How can I cause the logging calls in other.py to use a different logger without changing that module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I've come up with:

Using thread local data to store the contextual information, and using a Filter on the root loggers handlers to add this information to LogRecords before they are emitted.

```
context = threading.local()                                                      
context.name = None                                                              

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):                                             

    def filter(self, record):                                                    
        if context.name is not None:                                             
            record.name = "%s.%s" % (context.name, record.name)              
        return True
```

This is fine for me, because I'm using the logger name to indicate what task was being carried out when this message was logged.

I can then use context managers or decorators to make logging from a particular passage of code all appear as though it was logged from a particular child logger.

```
@contextlib.contextmanager                                                       
def logname(name):                                                               
    old_name = context.name                                                      
    if old_name is None:                                                         
        context.name = name                                                      
    else:                                                                        
        context.name = "%s.%s" % (old_name, name)                                

    try:                                                                                 
        yield                                                                        
    finally:                                                                         
        context.name = old_name                                                      

def as_logname(name):                                                            
    def decorator(f):                                                            
        @functools.wraps(f)                                                      
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):                                            
            with logname(name):                                                  
                return f(*args, **kwargs)                                        
        return wrapper                                                           
    return decorator
```

So then, I can do:

```
with logname("stuff"):
    logging.info("I'm doing stuff!")
    do_more_stuff()
```

or:

```
@as_logname("things")
def do_things():
    logging.info("Starting to do things")
    do_more_stuff()
```

The key thing being that any logging that `do_more_stuff()` does will be logged as if it were logged with either a "stuff" or "things" child logger, without having to change `do_more_stuff()` at all.

This solution would have problems if you were going to have different handlers on different child loggers.

Comment: Seems narcissistic to accept my own answer, but am doing so as that's the solution I'm using. Still open to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`logging.setLoggerClass`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.setLoggerClass) so that all loggers used by other modules use your logger subclass (emphasis mine):

> Tells the logging system to use the class klass when instantiating a logger. The class should define `__init__()` such that only a name argument is required, and the `__init__()` should call `Logger.__init__()`. **This function is typically called before any loggers are instantiated by applications which need to use custom logger behavior**.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer with an example?

Comment: maybe there's some special use case for this, but 99% of the time, its just a question of adding handlers.

Comment: Also, this sets the class for child loggers, but does not let you control the root logger. This won't, therefore, effect calls such as `logging.info("hello")` because they will use the root logger.

Answer (score 0):

This is what logging.handlers (or the handlers in the logging module) is for. In addition to creating your logger, you create one or more handlers to send the logging information to various places and add them to the root logger. Most modules that do logging create a logger that they use for there own purposes but depend on the controlling script to create the handlers. Some frameworks decide to be super helpful and add handlers for you.

Read the [logging docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), its all there.

(edit)

logging.basicConfig() is a helper function that adds a single handler to the root logger. You can control the format string it uses with the 'format=' parameter. If all you want to do is have all modules display "stuff", then use `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(levelname)s:stuff:%(message)s")`.

Comment: How does adding handlers make other modules you don't control log in your specified format?

Comment: @agf, suppose a module logs on "mighty.module". You create a handler, add a formatter to it and then add the handler to the logger. Usually, you do this at the root logger (logging.getLogger()), but you could do it anywhere (logging.getLogger("mighty.module").

Comment: @agf, the [logging howto](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#) has good examples.

Comment: That works OK if all other modules are using the root logger, but if they're using named loggers now you have to enumerate every one and update them with the new handler. The idea of using `setLoggerClass` is it doesn't matter what logger is being used elsewhere.

Comment: @agf, no the root handlers apply to everything. In general, when you add a handler to a.b.c, it gets a.b.c and all if its children. the root gets everybody.

Comment: @tdelaney This approach breaks down if the independent module has set `propogate` to `False` to prevent the message from percolating up.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure attaching handlers to the root logger is going to help in this case unless one hardcodes the logger name into the format.

Comment: @Wieland - but that's the point, isn't it? Handlers with their attached formater decide how and where the information is displayed, not the logger object. I don't think the poster was aware of how they work.

Comment: @Jonathan - there are many ways an module can control its own logging, including adding its own handlers, messing with propagate or even replacing the logging class completely. That's generally frowned upon, but that's why I specifically mentioned that some frameworks do that sort of thing.

Comment: I think this answer is probably missing the point. What if I have two functions, one uses child logger X and another that uses child logger Y, and both functions call do_more_stuff(), how can I make do_more_stuff() use the logger setup by the caller without changing do_more_stuff itself? Setting formatting on the root logger to have a hard coded value instead of %(name)s is a little more awkward than I was hoping for,

Comment: @SpoonMeiser - So you want do_more_stuff() to log something like "A: do more stuff" when called from function A and "B: do more stuff" when called from function B? You're right, I didn't understand that! Log messages can be intercepted as they flow down to the handlers. Maybe you could have a global variable with the current caller information and a filter that subs it in. Personally, I'd just stick with the way logging works but that's just me.

Comment: The motivation for this, is that some context to the log messages would be useful. If code that's processing X calls a function to do Y, it's useful for a log message that says that Y is being done to include the context that it's being done for processing X. Logging has lots of ways to do this, like child loggers and logger adapters, but they generally seem to require you to have to pass either a name, logger or adapter to each function, which would involve having to add an extra argument to almost every library function!

Comment: Also, could you make this work in a thread-safe way? If I wanted all logging on the root logger to include 'stuff' for the duration of one function in one thread, how do I ensure that logging calls from other threads aren't similarly marked?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser - you can record the current thread id (format="%(levelname)s:%(thread)d:stuff:%(message)s"). Logs from other threads would be intermixed, but you could still figure out which belong together.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem though - I'll want to add 'stuff' to the log output because 'stuff' is the task that the program is trying to achieve when it logs that message. Presumably other threads are working on other tasks and will want to be marking their log messages with a different string depending on what it is they're trying to achieve at that moment. Perhaps I need a more concrete example...

Comment: @SpoonMeiser - it's a difficult problem to solve and depends on how your code works. But, if a task is done on a single thread, you can log the equivalent of "thread-6 start task ABC", ... a bunch of other logs that include thread id... , "thread-6 end task ABC" and then you can post-process the log file to pull out the stuff between the start and the end for that thread.

Comment: That is certainly one way to handle this sort of problem, and is a reasonable way to do so. That would mean that adding 'stuff' to the log messages would then be redundant. However, I really want to have a clearer idea of what an individual log message is telling me without having to find lots of context. I'll certainly do that if I can't do what I actually want though.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser - okay, how about thread local storage? At the top of your program, create the storage `thread_local = threading.local()`, add task info at the start of a task `thread_local.task_id='ABC'`, create a logging Filter that adds it to the log record (inside the 'filter' method, do `record = getattr(thread_local, 'task_id', '')`) and then add task_id to your format message "%(task_id)s: %(subject)s".

Comment: @tdelaney I've been experimenting trying to do this, and the best solution I've found so far is very similar to that. Rather than modifying changing the formatting though, just modify the name attribute of the LogRecord.

Answer (score -1):

The `logging.{info,warning,…}` methods just  call the respective methods on a `Logger` object called `root` (cf. the [logging module source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/581da8df7ffd/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1632)), so if you know the `other` module is only calling the functions exported by the `logging` module, you can overwrite the `logging` module in `other`s namespace with your `logger` object:

```
import logging

import other

def do_stuff(logger):
    logger.info("doing stuff")
    other.do_more_stuff()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger("stuff")
    # Overwrite other.logging with your just-generated logger object:
    other.logging = logger
    do_stuff(logger)
```

Comment: No, this is not a good solution. There is no need to overwrite module loggers or to spend the time figuring out where the module stashes them.